# keep nan in groubpy, and transform mean

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to group a `dataframe` and keep the values that have `nan` in them to be in the `dataframe`. For that reason I'm using `fillna("")`.

Then I take the numeric column `l`, and I want to take the mean of the group. I'm running into an error `Could not convert "" to numeric`. It's doing that because my `l` column had some `nan` values in it.

Ideally after my groupby, I would like to convert those now "" values back to `nan` so I can complete the `.mean()` calc.

the work around that I've done is to turn only the columns I'm grouping by to "" first, doing the `.mean()`, then turning the "" values back to `nan` after its done. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import random
random.seed(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({
'a':[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(1000)],
'b':[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(1000)],
'c':[random.choice([0, 1, np.nan]) for x in range(1000)],
'd':[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(1000)],
'e':[random.choice([0, 1, np.nan]) for x in range(1000)],
'f':[random.choice(['id', 'id2']) for x in range(1000)],
'g':[random.choice(['apple', 'orange', 'pear']) for x in range(1000)],
'h':[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(1000)],
'i':[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(1000)],
'j':[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(1000)],
'k':[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(1000)],
'l':[random.choice([1, 2, 34, 6, 36, 990, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]) for x in range(1000)]
})


df['mean_l'] = df.fillna("").groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'])['l'].transform(lambda x: x.mean())
```

Comment: A smaller sample + an expected output would be helpful here! How about this: `df['mean_l'] = df.fillna('').assign(l=df.l).groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'])['l'].transform('mean')`. Does it give you your desired result?

Comment: I started working through a smaller sample, but your solution works. Thank you. If you post it I'll accept and close out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to avoid to fill-na values in the `l` column in this case as it is your target column.

One way would be to reassign the column `l` with assign.

```
df['mean_l'] = (df.fillna('')
                  .assign(l=df.l)
                  .groupby(list('abcdefghijk'))['l']
                  .transform('mean'))
```